# Delete Excel sheet randomly fails

Tags: c++, excel, msdn, catia

I am trying to delete Excel sheet via C++ code but randomly it fails.
Here is the code:

```
HRESULT hr = AutoWrap(DISPATCH_METHOD, NULL, pXlSheet, L"Delete", 0);
```

This function returns `S_OK` even delete sheet failed but the sheet isn't deleted from the workbook.

Note: The system gives error sound, if delete sheet failed.

Comment: Maybe the excel file is locked by another program?

Comment: It's not locked by another program.

Comment: what is the OS, sometimes there is a problem of level integrity.

Comment: how to suppress delete sheet warning?
I suspect that is the cause of issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs because while deleting sheets sometimes warning prompt appears even deleting empty sheet.

To suppress warning prompt i used the below snippet and it works fine.

Code snippet:

```
VARIANT vBool;
vBool.vt=VT_BOOL;
vBool.boolVal=FALSE;

hr = AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYPUT, NULL, _pXlApp, L"DisplayAlerts",1,vBool);
```

This method returns S_OK:)